# what is convenience constructor. do I need to retain the object returned by convenience constructor

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

what is convenience constructor.

if I use init method like this

```
 NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];
 [self setCount:zero];
 [zero release];
```

it is me to retain or release zero object. but if I do like this

```
NSNumber *zero = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
    [self setCount:zero];
```

the apple documents says no need to retain or release zero.

what is the detail memory state of when using `numberWithInteger:`? the object returned by Class method `numberWithInteger:` doesn't have the retain count 1 or the zero object retain count 1? It seems the count of the object pointed by pointer zero is already 1 when returned by `numberWithInteger:`. If I invoke `setCount:`, the count plus 1 to 2. there seems a potential memory leak.

Comment: You get confused because of the new thing that plays an important role here: the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's convenience of convenience constructor, that object already moved in autorelease pool and you don't need release it.

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
```

implemented as:

```
+ (NSNumber) numberWithInteger:(NSInteger) value
{
    return [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: values] autorelease];
}
```

You should use same patter for implementing yours own convenience constructors.

Comment: what is the scope of the zero object returned by numberwithinteger:

Comment: Use `[[self alloc] init...]` rather than hardcoding the class name to support subclassing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, yes, this will be convenient. Please edit my post.

Comment: @llch, it's moved inside current autorelease pool. So it will be deallocated with autorelease pool if someone else already not retained it.

Comment: @llch, the scope of zero object in this case is the same as scope of zero variable, that is the object will be alive until the end of the method/function.
Basically, the object created by convenience constructor is always alive inside the scope it was created in.

Answer (score 0):

Memory state:

1) `NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];`

During do this, it will alloc NSNumber with retain count 1. But you're responsible for to release this memory.

2) `NSNumber *zero = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];`

During do this, it will also alloc NSNumber and do assign operation. It also have retain count 1. But you don't worry about release this memory. Because this method `numberWithInteger:` return **autorelease object**. So if you will retain this object, you've to release that retain count.

**Note:** When the retain count of memory going to zero, it'll automatically dealloc from memory. Idea behind this memory management is retain count of allocated memory, if the allocated memory have retain count 1 or more for along time but didn't use in any run loop, it'll consider as leak.

REF: To know more about memory management , [read this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MemoryManagement.html).

Comment: what is the scope of the zero object returned by numberwithinteger:

Comment: it's an autorelease object, which will remain in memory until run loop end.  That is if you call `numberWithInteger:` in ONE method, scope of  object which returned by this method, will maintain until end of ONE method.